# Copy all fields to larger structure

Tags: matlab, structure

I have two structures, `A` and `B`, and I would like to copy all of the fields from `B` into `A`. I can't do a simple assignment of `A=B;` because `A` has many other fields that I want to remain unaffected. For now I've been assigning each field individually by name. Is there a good way to copy all of fields from `B` to `A` without having to assign each one individually? The best I've been able to come up with is assigning them all in a loop using `A.(fieldname)` syntax, but I was hoping there might be a one-line solution out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to copy only *some* fields, then the dynamic field referencing is the best approach.

```
fields_to_copy = {'one', 'two'};

for k = 1:numel(fields_to_copy)
    A.(fields_to_copy{k}) = B.(fields_to_copy{k});
end
```

If you don't want to overwrite any fields in `A`, you could create your list of fields to copy in the following way

```
fields_to_copy = setdiff(fieldnames(B), fieldnames(A));
```

Alternately, if you have specific fields in `A` that you'd like to keep

```
fields_to_copy = setdiff(fieldnames(B), {'keep', 'these', 'fields'});
```